# Appium Validation

Tags: android, validation, appium

how are you?
I would like to check if in Appium there is some possibility of validation like checking if the element was found and if it was not found, continue to the next instruction and check the next element? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try catch will solve your problem, try once if not let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend Venkatesh answer. 
Appium has an Exception called NoSuchElementException that you could use to catch this kind of situation. For example in my appium projects I always implement my own method to find elements

```
public WebElement findElement(By by){
        WebElement wElement = null;     
        if(driver != null){
            try{
                wElement = driver.findElement(by);
            }catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            }
        }
        return wElement;
    }
```

Like this I make it easier and I just need to check if the object is null or not...

```
public boolean isToolbarPresent(){
    WebElement wElement = findElement(...);
    if(wElement == null || !wElement.isEnabled()){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```